# GKsession will finish in 10min is there any way to continue more longer?

Tags: xcode, background, gksession

I created a application that will send a data by bluetooth using a GKsession from background.
It is woking to send a data but , data sending will finish even i recall the function ever 30seconds. Is there any way to continue for more longer time?

Or is there an any limit for Iphone or BTM?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there's any enforced limit but it's a good practice to define a ping function to broadcast a small message to all connected peers at a small interval like 15 seconds.